# Define a Label in the main and use it in another method

Tags: java, label

Is it possible to create a label in the main method then use in another method ?

Please consider the following simple example to illustrate my question.

```
public class work{
//***********************************************************
static public class listen implements Runnable{

    public listen(....)
    {
       ......
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ....

        if(Msg.startsWith("Work Done"))
        {
             break serverSock;   //HOW CAN I DO THIS ??
       }
    }
  }
//********************************************************
public static void main(String[] args){

    Thread L = new Thread (new listen(...));
    L.start();

    //main thread is busy ...

    serverSock:
    sock.close();   
 }                    
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot do this.  Rewrite your logic to exit normally.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen
Thanks, I did what you said and problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `flag` in the `listen` method

and `if statement` in the `main` method