# Jumping out of for-loop including a recursive method with for-loop (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, label

This is my first post, so sorry if I post incorrect or incomplete, I will answer every question and I am open for improvements.

My main method has a for-loop with a recursive method in it, the recursive method also has a for-loop (the recursive method basically replaces a lot of nested for-loops). When a specific case is reached, I want to jump out of the recursive method and out of the for-loop in my main. For visualization:

```
public static void main(..)

for (int i = 0, i < 100 ; i++) {
   //do something
   recursivemethod(...)
}
//jump here, if case in method is reached
------------------------
recursivemethod (...) 
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    //do something
    if (case reached) {//jump out of loop in main}
    else {recursivemethod(modified)}
    
}
```

As I cannot label my for-loop in main and `break Label;` in my method (to my knowledge), I tried using a boolean, but because of for-loops and/or recursive call, boolean switches back and has not the wanted effect.

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595545/define-a-label-in-the-main-and-use-it-in-another-method) where the user later added his solution, but didn't specify it enough for me to understand and how to implement this in my code, the user was last seen years ago, so I cannot ask him. Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does your recursive method return something? You would want to break out from the loop based on the return of the method.

Comment: The recursive method is a void, so it currently does not return something. It could be an idea to return a boolean, false if the case is not reached and true if it was reached. Is that true, and what would I have to add in the for-loop?

Comment: Something like that,  see the answer from @Peter Trencansky.

Comment: Thanks for your help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to return boolean from your recursive method. E. g. true means that recursive call8ng should stop and exit loop

```
for (int i = 0, i < 100 ; i++) {
    //do something
    if(recursivemethod(...))
        break;
 }
```

Recursive method

```
boolean  recursivemethod (...) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
    //do something
    if (case reached) {return true;}
    else {return recursivemethod(modified)}
    return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Addition: because of recursive call, I needed to add an if-statement. The final, working recursive method looks like this:

for (...)
if (case reached) {return true} 
if (recursivemethod) {return true}